# Split a string using C++ boost::split without splitting inside quoted text

Tags: c++, boost, split

I am using

```
boost::split(strs, r_strCommandLine, boost::is_any_of("\t "));
```

to spit a string into tokens for parsing a simple script. So far, so good. However, for the following string

```
command_name first_argument "Second argument which is a quoted string."
```

i would like my tokens to be

```
strs[0] = command_name
strs[1] = first_argument
strs[2] = "Second argument which is a quoted string."
```

Of course, I could search for quote characters at beginning and ending of tokens and merging using " " delimiters the tokens between the the occurrence of a token beginning with a quote and a token ending with a quote to recreate the quoted string but I am wondering if there is a more efficient/elegant way of doing this. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I am confused by your question. Is the first paragraph of this question related in any way to the remainder of the question?

Comment: [`boost::tokenizer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/tokenizer/introduc.htm) may have the functionality you require.

Comment: Splitting may be too simplistic, since you really want some form of *parsing*.

Comment: @Yakk Yes. The string to split would looks like string("command_name first_argument \"Second argument which is a quoted string.\"" )

Comment: @Robᵩ No. This is weird. The first paragraph is a comment I made yesterday on another post. If I edit this current question, I do not see the first paragraph at all, so I can't remove it... weird behavior.

Comment: If you're trying to parse command line arguments, you may be better off using [Boost.ProgramOptions](http://www.boost.org/libs/program_options) instead of `boost::split`.

Comment: @Christian: I edited the paragraph out, subject to approval.  You may have an edit to approve!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Example using [`boost::tokenizer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/tokenizer):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::string;

#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
using boost::tokenizer;
using boost::escaped_list_separator;

typedef tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> > so_tokenizer;

int main()
{
    string s("command_name first_argument "
             "\"Second argument which is a quoted string.\"");

    so_tokenizer tok(s, escaped_list_separator<char>('\\', ' ', '\"'));
    for(so_tokenizer::iterator beg=tok.begin(); beg!=tok.end(); ++beg)
    {
        cout << *beg << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
command_name
first_argument
Second argument which is a quoted string.
```

See demo at https://ideone.com/gwCpug .

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the quotes? I need the output to be like:
`command_name`
`first_argument`
`"Second argument which is a quoted string."`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this solution is portable (we violate the const condition for `bool operator() (char ch) const`), but it works.

This solution is interesting in theory, I would not use it in a real project.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class split_q {
public:
    split_q() : in_q(false) {}
    bool operator() (char ch) const
    {
        if (ch == '\"') in_q = !in_q;
        return !in_q && ch == ' ';
    }

private:
    mutable bool in_q;

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string in = "command_name first_argument \"Second argument which is a quoted string.\" additional_argument";
    std::vector<std::string> res;
    boost::algorithm::split(res, in, split_q());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << res[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
command_name
first_argument
"Second argument which is a quoted string."
additional_argument
```

Comment: You can fix the `const` breaking this by storing `bool* in_q` instead of a `mutable` `in_q`.  And a backslash escape state should be easy to add.

Comment: My concern is not to use the mutable keyword, but the actual violation of immutability

Comment: There is no violation of immutability if you stored a pointer in the functor.  The big problem with mutating the functor is that you depend on the algorithm to use exactly one instance of your functor, and not make a copy -- if that happens, you run into problems.  The only problem I can see with the pointer version is that the algorithm could run it out-of-order.

Comment: @Yakk Thank you, you described in detail the problems of this approach