# Split string with quoted variables

Tags: c++, string

How can I split a string of the following format in C++?:

```
"word","otherword","something else","1"
```

Comment: The question is not clear at all. Split into what? The string is already splited in the usual sense of the word.

Comment: seems like a very common question, should search before asking it.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406387/split-a-string-using-c-boostsplit-without-splitting-inside-quoted-text/13406735#13406735

Comment: Split into an vector or something else.
I have already find the topics you are referring to, but they don't give a clear answer on how you need to split a line of quoted variables into a vector.

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear enough