# Splitting string selectively on spaces

Tags: c++

My command is:

```
move 1 "South Africa" "Europe"
```

Code:

```
do 
{
  cut = text.find(' ');
  if (cut == string::npos) 
  {
    params.push_back(text);
  } 
  else 
  {
    params.push_back(text.substr(0, cut));
    text = text.substr(cut + 1);
  }
}  
while (cut != string::npos);
```

The problem is that `South Africa` is getting split into `South` and `Africa`, I need it to remain `South Africa`.

Parameters after cut:

```
1, South, Africa, Europe
```

And I need it to be:

```
1, South Africa, Europe
```

How can I do this? With regex?

Another example of a command:

```
move 3 "New Island" "South Afrika"
```

and my code cut after ' ' and I need in the params where I push back

```
3, New Island, South Africa
```

My code makes:

```
3,"New,Island","South,Africa"
```

Comment: Please paste more complete examples of your input, what the desired output is, preferably with some more complete code sample.

Comment: If the quotes are typed in the input, then the input is unambiguous and you can parse accurately by spotting when a 'word' starts with a double quote and looking for the first closing quote instead of the first space.  If the quotes are not included, the input is ambiguous and you will have to provide a way (heuristic) for disambiguating it, or redesign the acceptable to be unambiguous.  Remember that you need a mechanism to handled embedded quotes — at least in general.

Comment: consider using a stream and using `operator>>` which will extract each word delimited by a space.

Comment: @andre maybe a example?

Comment: Maybe you should tokenize your string based on the " symbol instead and then throw out empty strings/strings of only whitespace? Or if we're interpreting the " symbol as a string literal, you really need to be able to delimit your elements by *something* so you can split them up, else you're gonna need to try to match against a dictionary

Comment: Your answer might be [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406387/split-a-string-using-c-boostsplit-without-splitting-inside-quoted-text).

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your string using `std::stringstream` and `std::getline`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string text("move 3 \"New Island\" \"South Afrika\"");
    std::string command, count, country1, country2, temp;
    std::stringstream ss(text);

    ss >> command >> count;
    ss.str("");
    ss << text;
    std::getline(ss, temp, '\"');
    std::getline(ss, country1, '\"');
    std::getline(ss, temp, '\"');
    std::getline(ss, country2, '\"');

    std::cout << command << ", " << count << ", " <<
        country1 << ", " << country2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```